# putting title inside div on click

Tags: jquery, variables, click

Currently using:

```
$(function () {
    $(".playbtn").on("button", "click", function (e) {
        var title = $(this).attr('name');
    });
});

$('.movie-title').html(title);
```

I am trying to get the content of name for playbtn on click and store it in a variable. Then put this content into a div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Run the expected actions *inside* the desired function
- Your `delegated element selector` is in the wrong place. Should be

```
$(function () {
    $(".playbtn").on("click", "button", function() {
        var title = $(this).attr('name');
        $('.movie-title').html(title);
    });
});
```

IF you want to use that variable inside another function you need to make a *global* use of your `var` like:

```
$(function () {

    var title = '';       // DEFINED

    $(".playbtn").on("click", "button", function() {
         title = $(this).attr('name');    // SET
        $('.movie-title').html(title);    // USED
    });

    $("#alertTitleButton").on("click", function() {
         alert( title );                  // USED
    });

});
```

Read more: <kbd>**[jquery.com/on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**</kbd>

<sup>*Post Scriptum:*
 Be aware that the above will target all elements `.movie-title` so be more specific using your jQuery selectors:</sup>

<kbd>**[jquery.com/selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**</kbd> <kbd>**[jquery.com/traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)**</kbd>

Comment: what if i want to use that variable in another function?